# How to pass data from MQL4 to C# DLL

Tags: c#, dll, mql4

I would like to ask how to pass some kind of data, like string to my C# DLL. This questions has been answered for C++: [How to pass argument by reference from MQL4 to C++ DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520941/how-to-pass-argument-by-reference-from-mql4-to-c-dll)

However in my case I want my C# code to get this value from MQL4 and then do something with it (so all this while in the C# code).

It's probably a similar approach, but is this still the best way to go, and could someone provide a minimum example of doing this in C#?

Answer (score 2):

### The Best Way to go?

My one would be to integrate "over" a principally neutral ZeroMQ channel.

MQL4 will sit on one side, C# or whatever other process ( python, GoLang, Erlang, FORTRAN, MATLAB, ... ) will sit on remote side, each agent-side having a chance to have also an N+M load/balancing or robustness resilience added.

Using the same byte-packing mapper on either side will enforce interoperability, even if MetaTrader Terminal platform will make any next shift of paradagms ( as it did in past, having moved **`string`** datatype into actually being a **`#pragma`**-decorated **`struct`** and similar low level surprises ).

This way one will never have to re-visit the API for any external re-factoring introduced implementation revision for gaining the lost integration back into production.

---

### Minimum Example of doing this?

Feel free to [study and re-use **many** of ZeroMQ examples posted **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D) or the ZeroMQ API documentation and the C# bindings available.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I would still love to see a minimal working example, perhaps using hte ZeroMQ API.

Comment: A working example of what? Your O/P did not contain a SLOC on any such. Feel free to bring a code you have tried to design and show where / how it fails to work in spite of the API documentation or a use-case. This is a standard StackOverflow policy.

Comment: I added the way I;m trying to get an integer into the C# function.